# Building a (big) sparse matrix out of many (big) dicts

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I have a series of dicts of the form:

```
dict_k:{(i,j):d_ij}
```

where i and j are integers corresponding to the indices in the sparse matrix to be built and d_ij a float number. Dictionaries can contain up to O(1 Million) values

I have about 160 such dictionaries, each dictionary is about 16 MegaBytes. Dictionaries may or may not contain duplicate keys with duplicate values, that is you could find the (0,0):1.25 key/value couple in two different dictionaries for example.

I want to build a sparse matrix containing out of these dictionaries.
The entries of the matrix would be given by all of the {(i,j):d_ij} couples in all of the dictionaries.

My naive approach is to build a huge dictionary out of all dictionaries like so :

```
bigDict={}
for i in range(160):
    with open(dictionary_path, "rb") as fp:   
        bigDict.update(pickle.load(fp))
```

Then retrieve the columns/row indices and their corresponding coefficients to build a scipy coo format sparse matrix with the line (`coo_matrix((coefficients, (rows, columns)), [shape=(M, N)])`).

But this makes my computer freeze when building the huge dict, do you have any smarter way of doing it ?
My end end goal is to use this sparse matrix to perform matrix vector multiplications.

an example dict :

```
 {(0, 1704510): 0.125,
 (0, 1704511): 0.089,
 (0, 1704512): 0.044,
 (0, 1704513): 0.021,
 (0, 1704514): 0.037,
 (0, 1704515): 0.032,
 (0, 1704516): 0.021,
 (0, 1704517): 0.013,
 (0, 502593): 0.089,
 (0, 502594): 0.125,
 (0, 502595): 0.089,
 (0, 502596): 0.044,
 (0, 502597): 0.032,
 (0, 502598): 0.037,
 (0, 502599): 0.032,
 (0, 502600): 0.021,
 (0, 129844): 0.044,
 (0, 129845): 0.089,
 (0, 129846): 0.125,
 (0, 129847): 0.089,
 (0, 129848): 0.021,
 (0, 129849): 0.032,
 (0, 129850): 0.037,
 (0, 129851): 0.032,
 (0, 28314): 0.021,
 (0, 28315): 0.044,
 (0, 28316): 0.089,
 (0, 28317): 0.125,
 (0, 28318): 0.013,
 (0, 28319): 0.021,
 (0, 28320): 0.032,
 (0, 28321): 0.037,
 (0, 4917): 1.0,
 (0, 4918): 0.354,
 (0, 4919): 0.089,
 (0, 4920): 0.032,
 (0, 4921): 0.125,
 (0, 4922): 0.089,
 (0, 4923): 0.044,
 (0, 4924): 0.021,
 (0, 615): 0.354,
 (0, 616): 1.0,
 (0, 617): 0.354,
 (0, 618): 0.089,
 (0, 619): 0.089,
 (0, 620): 0.125,
 (0, 621): 0.089,
 (0, 622): 0.044,
 (0, 45): 0.089,
 (0, 46): 0.354,
 (0, 47): 1.0,
 (0, 48): 0.354,
 (0, 49): 0.044,
 (0, 50): 0.089,
 (0, 51): 0.125,
...
 (13, 675): 0.354,
 (13, 680): 0.089,
 (13, 684): 0.089,
 (13, 685): 0.125,
 ...}
```

The matrix is of size  5Millionx5Million approximately

Comment: How many items do the dicts have, and how many different column/row indices and values are there overall?

Comment: Some test data would be useful.

Comment: You could try "retrieving" the `coo` inputs one dict at a time (or possibly partial groups of them).  And then collect these inputs in 3 lists.  Finally `hstack` them to make the inputs for your big `coo`.  But I don't know if that's any better from a memory stand point than your `dict` update approach.

Comment: @KellyBundy how can I provide such big data on this site ? should I make a link to a cloud thing ?

Comment: I didn't mean your whole real data, I wouldn't be able to use that anyway and might not want to even if I were. I meant just something small so that an answer's solution can actually be tested (I posted mine without testing, which I pretty much ***never*** do, and I don't feel comfortable with it). Could be an explicit list of three dicts with three items each, for example. Or could be a little code that generates larger random but realistic data. That could also write pickle files for more realism.

Answer (score 0):

`pickle` seems to create different objects for equal ints/floats, so probably most of your memory usage comes from the keys and values, not from the dictionaries themselves. You could try to deduplicate them, for example:

```
dedup = {}.setdefault
def d(x):
    return dedup(x, x)

bigDict={}
for i in range(160):
    with open(dictionary_path, "rb") as fp:   
        for (x, y), z in pickle.load(fp).items():
            bigDict[d(x), d(y)] = d(z)
```